# Compare two binary trees to see if they have the same structure

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

another easy one but I can't seem to get it.  I need to write a method that compares the structures of two binary trees and returns weather they are the same or not.  The data and data types are not important only the structures.  Here are some examples:

[image: Examples!]

Here is the code I have so far.  I think it is really close.

```
public boolean sameStructure(OrderedSet<E> other) {
    if (other.size() != size)
        return false;
    return sameStructureHelp(other, root, other.root);
}

private boolean sameStructureHelp(OrderedSet<E> other, TreeNode ref,
        TreeNode otherRef) {
    if (otherRef == null && ref != null)
        return false;
    if (otherRef != null && ref == null)
        return false;
    sameStructureHelp(other, ref.left, otherRef.left);
    sameStructureHelp(other, ref.right, otherRef.right);
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you pasted is mostly right, only missing a critical piece: instead of just checking the left and right subtrees, you should return their `and` value, which would mean if the trees rooted in the current nodes satisfies the condition for being the same stucture.

Comment: What is your assertion? After a closer look, it seems that if the two nodes are null at the same time, your code would throw a NullPointerException, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ziyao Wei
Here is the code which solved the problem:

```
public boolean sameStructure(OrderedSet<E> other) {
    if (other.size() != size)
        return false;
    return sameStructureHelp(other, root, other.root);
}

private boolean sameStructureHelp(OrderedSet<E> other, TreeNode ref,
        TreeNode otherRef) {
    if (otherRef == null && ref != null)
        return false;
    if (otherRef != null && ref == null)
        return false;
    if (otherRef == null && ref == null)
        return true;

    return sameStructureHelp(other, ref.left, otherRef.left) 
        && sameStructureHelp(other, ref.right, otherRef.right);

}
```